# Windows 8.1 Connecting to Wrong Wireless Network

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, windows-8.1

I have a Windows 8.1 laptop (Lenovo Y510p, if it matters) which I have configured to connect to my home wireless network. The network works mostly fine, and Windows is set up to remember it correctly.

However, when I start the computer or resume it from sleep mode, it will sometimes decide to connect to a nearby, unseccured wireless network instead. This is not a network I've ever told it to connect to, and it has a random uncommon SID "Apple Network a89b9c" which I'm sure I've never used anywhere else. Despite that, it will frequently connect to that network in preference to my own home network, and despite the fact that I can't get any actual connectivity through that network.

Ideally I would like to stop Windows from promiscuously connecting to any unsecured WiFi that happens to be in the area. Failing that, I would at least like to block that particular network. I have Googled for this but with no luck. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried already? Have you checked the WiFi adapter's utility for an option about automatically connecting to unsecured networks?  Editing your question and providing exactly which network adapter is in question will help get a more definitive answer.

Comment: Ah, so it's actually a "feature" of the Intel Drivers, not Windows. Thanks! @techie007, if you post that as an answer I'll mark it as correct.